# Python Read File Content

Tags: python, file

In Python, how to read a file content only (not including attribute and filename), like using InputStream in Java?
I need a method that works for various file formats

I've tried this

```
with open(filePath, "rb") as imageFile:
    str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
    M=str.decode()
    print(M)
```

The problem is, I will get error for any object after that block

Comment: Did you "Google" it?

Comment: This is an _extremely_ basic task in Python, covered in innumerable tutorials. You are expected to do a non-zero amount of research before posting a new question to this site.

Answer (score 5):

The most basic way is like so:

```
with open("filename.txt") as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

The variable contents will now contain a string of everything in the file. More information is in the Python Documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).